# ec2 php artisan migrate SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: laravel, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, artisan-migrate

I am running Laravel 8.83.23 on EC2.  The application is working fine.

I connect to the instance using EC2 Instance Connect and try to check the state of migration:

php artisan migrate:status

I get  'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused'

Which I do not uderstand as the application is working.  I verified that .env has some effect when I changed 127.0.0.1 to localhost and got a  'file not found' error.

[another group had similar trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283329/ec2-laravel-migrations-run-as-many-times-as-the-instances)

I tried clearing the artisan caches.

.env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=<key>
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://<url>/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=rent
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=<key>
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=https://<url>/

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=rent
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Comment: Is the database on the same EC2 machine? Is it MySQL? if you run `mysql` command so you try to connect to the MySQL server with CLI, can you do so?

Comment: Good catch,  thx.  The db is on RDS.  I get a socket can't connect error with mysql, so likely an IAM setting.  Of course,  the site does not run on the EBS connect instance.

Comment: So, I am not sure about your setup, but do you have the EC2 machine IP whitelisted on the RDS instance? (security group), or do you have `0.0.0.0 - 3306` open for outbound and inbound?

Comment: Also forgot to ask: are the RDS and EC2 instances on the same VPC?

Comment: They are both on the same VPC.  I am not sure how to grant access.

Comment: This is the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/security-groups.html, the idea is to edit the "basic" or default assigned security group of the RDS instance to allow traffic to reach it. If you do not have all traffic inboud/outbound, no one can reach it (even private network). Only allow the EC2 IP! This link should help you: https://catalog.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/workshops/8efd4edb-2b91-49fd-b1b8-3e3b5e71aa03/en-US/rds/rds1#add-a-vpc-instance-security-group

Comment: I added both the private and public IPs of the EC2 connect instance to the CIDR/IP - Inbound RDS instance Security group rules to no avail  :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252651/discussion-between-smalltalkman-and-matiaslauriti).